# C++ incrementing a globally declared counter

Tags: c++

say I had a counter declared globally that incremented in another function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count = 0;

string passorFail(int x, int y)
{

    if (x > y)
    {
        return "pass";
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        return "fail";
    }
}

int main()
{

    int x = 10;
    int y = 5;

    passorFail(x, y);
    std::cout << "Count: " << count << std::endl;
}
```

However when this runs it just returns 0, where as Id like it to return 1. I know people will say declare within the function but for the purposes of what im doing count has to be global. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I got [compilation error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/scAD8vwMWqmKMc1I). This looks like one example of how using `using namespace std;` is bad.

Comment: The problem is that you return before you increase the number.

Comment: You `return "pass"` before you increment the counter, the `count++;` won't ever be executed.. C++ `return` isn't the same as setting `result` in Delphi. VTC as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
return "pass";
count++;
```

you are returning from the function before incrementing count. Your compiler should warn that `count++;` is unreachable code.

You need:

```
count++;
return "pass";
```

Also, please don't use `using namespace std;`. e.g. if `<iostream>` brings in the name `count` (which it's allowed to do), the code will not do what you want.

Comment: ill give this a crack. And yea i dont use ```using namespace std;``` but for simplications sake i used it here

Comment: Ok, but be aware that "simplifying" the code like this actually changes the meaning of the code (in unexpected ways, if you're not used to it).

Comment: @DickChang You didn't _"simplify"_ anything. You already wrote `std::cout`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: but not for `std::string` (so missing `#include`, probably propose `<bits/stdc++.h>` instead of `<string>` ;) or return `const char*`/`auto`).